# how to write while loop for translator

Tags: javascript

I was trying to solve my code for java script. But I noticed that my while loop is not working. Basically I am trying to make a pig latin translator. Can anyone please suggest me what I should do to run the code?
Here is my code:

```
s = "this is a sentence"

words = s.split(' ')

document.write(words.length)

//document.write(" ")

//document.write(words[1])

var empty = ["this","is","sentence"]

counter = 0

while(counter == words.length){

    first_letter = words[counter].substring(0,words[counter].length)+"ay";

    //new = words[first_letter]+"ay"

    empty.push(first_letter);

    counter = counter + 1;               
    }
document.write(empty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you put a wrong condition in your while loop. In the first instance itself, it returns false because `counter=0` and `words.length = 4`. It only execute the code when `counter=4`. I think what you need to put there is `while(counter < words.length)`, which means execute the code until the last letter of the word. Tell me if it works or not.

To put the first letter in the last and then add the 'ay' here is an example that might be helpful.

```js
var word = "Word";
var first_letter = word.substring(0,1);
var word_without_first_letter = word.slice(1,word.length);
var new_word = word_without_first_letter + first_letter+"ay";
alert(new_word);
```

Comment: Yes!! Finally it is running. I am very thankful to you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good job! @ktas I would greatly appreciate it if you accept this one as a correct answer ;)

Comment: But in line 9 what I was trying to do is remove the first letter of each word and place it at the end. So that hello would be elloh and then I wanted to add "ay". But the output is

Comment: 4thisay,isay,aay,sentenceay

Comment: Can you suggest how I should approach to this problem?

Comment: @ktas I added what you asked in my answer. Kindly edit your question also.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "this is a sentence"

words = s.split(' ')

document.write(words.length)

//document.write(" ")

//document.write(words[1])

var empty = ["this","is","sentence"]

counter = 0

while(counter !== words.length){

    first_letter = words[counter].substring(1,words[counter].length)+words[counter].slice(0,1)+"ay";

    //new = words[first_letter]+"ay"

    empty.push(first_letter);

    counter = counter + 1;               
    }
document.write(empty)
```

The condition used in the while loop was not right.Counter has to be "not equal" to word.length then only it will go inside while loop.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. It worked but the problem is in "first_letter" I was trying to write the code so that it will make "this"--> "histay"  , "is"--> "siay", and so on.

Comment: I think I could not write substring properly. Can you please help me?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in line 9 what I was trying to do is remove the first letter of each word and place it at the end. So that "this" would be "hist" and then I wanted to add "ay". But the output is 4thisay,isay,aay,sentenceay.. Can you suggest how I should approach to this problem?

Comment: i have edited my answer , now u can check it, it should work fine.

Comment: @ktas can u close the question by marking the answer right.